# How can I query an NTP server under Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntp

I am not interested in synchronizing my local clock with the remote server. I only want to query it and print the result.

I would have assumed that there is a port of `ntpq` for Windows, but was unable to find any.

All other NTP clients I could find, they always want to install themselves as a service or make it otherwise clear that they want to synchronize my local time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check a system's current NTP configuration?](http://superuser.com/questions/425233/how-can-i-check-a-systems-current-ntp-configuration)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
C:\> w32tm /stripchart /computer:foo
Tracking foo [1.2.3.4].
The current time is 19/07/2012 17:39:48 (local time).
17:39:48 d:-00.0000840s o:-25.3004160s  [@                          |                           ]
17:39:50 d:-00.0000680s o:-25.3070080s  [@                          |                           ]
17:39:52 d:-00.0000690s o:-25.2987405s  [@                          |                           ]
17:39:54 d:-00.0000680s o:-25.3071530s  [@                          |                           ]
17:39:56 d:-00.0000690s o:-25.2993985s  [@                          |                           ]
17:39:58 d:-00.0000680s o:-25.3070270s  [@                          |                           ]
```

Wireshark shows NTP packets being generated by this. <strike>Some versions of w32tm have a /query option</strike>

```
C:\>w32tm /stripchart /computer:us.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:5
Tracking us.pool.ntp.org [208.87.221.228:123].
Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 19/07/2012 18:36:32.
18:36:32, +03.3575094s
18:36:34, +03.3573679s
18:36:37, +03.3572986s
18:36:39, +03.3570290s
18:36:41, +03.3565357s
```

Comment: To my understanding the `/query` is to query configuration parameters. I used it all day :D

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know if this works as expected, because I receive a valid time whatever I put as computer value.

Comment: @Ozkan [ask a question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) 1) quoting what you saw and explaining 2) what you expected to see instead and 3) why.

Answer (score 9):

Bytefusion's [ntpquery](http://www.bytefusion.com/download/) seems to be incredibly old, but works. Sadly, it requires initial installation, but the application files will work fine when copied to another system.

[image]

Comment: Installation not needed: open in 7-Zip, extract ntpquery.exe, and use as-is.

Answer (score 7):

The latest and greatest NTP check tool I could find was this: https://www.galsys.co.uk/categories/ntp-server-checker.html

[image]

Comment: This I especially like because it is portable.

Comment: FYI : [4 security vendors and no sandboxes flagged this file as malicious](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/07c00df982d362c48844c2ee370a3dcd4862ee6c3aca71a2042b8aa0446baaeb/behavior)   

"Scheduled Task/Job T1053
Creates COM task schedule object (often to register a task for autostart)
 Command and Scripting Interpreter"

"Very long command line found T1059
Very long cmdline option found, this is very uncommon (may be encrypted or packed)"

Comment: Looking at the sources in [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), this is a .NET Fx 4.0 VB.NET app with no malicious code i could find.